# Градиент закругленного бордюра кнопки

Tags: html, css, svg, less

Как сделать градиент закругленного бордюра кнопки с прозрачным содержимым?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К примеру, в простом варианте — нет возможности задать градиент для border-bottom, border-top

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         .box
         {
         margin:50px auto;
         width:250px;
         height:300px;
         border-top:1px solid #3ACFD5;
         border-bottom:1px solid #3a4ed5;
         border-radius:7px;
         -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
         -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
         box-sizing:border-box;
         background-position:0 0,100% 0;
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         -webkit-background-size:20px 100%;
         -moz-background-size:20px 100%;
         background-size:1px 100%;
         background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#3acfd5 0%,#3a4ed5 100%),-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#3acfd5 0%,#3a4ed5 100%);
         background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#3acfd5 0%,#3a4ed5 100%),-moz-linear-gradient(top,#3acfd5 0%,#3a4ed5 100%);
         background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#3acfd5 0%,#3a4ed5 100%),-o-linear-gradient(top,#3acfd5 0%,#3a4ed5 100%);
         background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#3acfd5 0%,#3a4ed5 100%),linear-gradient(to bottom,#3acfd5 0%,#3a4ed5 100%)
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="box"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Идеальный вариант, теоретически можно с помощью clip-path осуществить заливку середины маской с прозрачностью и выставить отступы от краев, но на данный момент — код работает наоборот и нужно инвертировать маску.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/less">
.border-test {
  margin: 2em;
  height: 100px;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: purple;
  .border-squircle(10%; 50%);
}

.border-squircle(@radius-x; @radius-y) {
  .loop(@radius-x; @radius-y; 359; 100% 0);
}

.loop(@radius-x; @radius-y; @counter; @list) when (@counter >= 0) {
  @cos-x: cos(unit(@counter, deg));
  @x: pow(abs(@cos-x), unit(@radius-x) / 100) * 50 * abs(@cos-x + 0.0000000001) / (@cos-x + 0.0000000001) + 50;
  
  @sin-y: sin(unit(@counter, deg));
  @y: pow(abs(@sin-y), unit(@radius-y) / 100) * 50 * abs(@sin-y + 0.0000000001) / (@sin-y + 0.0000000001) + 50;
  
  @percent-x: percentage(round(@x, 1) / 100);
  @percent-y: percentage(round(@y, 1) / 100);
  
  @new-list: @percent-x @percent-y, @list;
  .loop(@radius-x; @radius-y; (@counter - 1); @new-list);
}

.loop(@radius-x; @radius-y; @counter; @list) when (@counter < 0) {
  clip-path: polygon(@list);
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="border-test"></div>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Пробовал вариант с SVG - он растягивается сильно, даже при применение атрибута non-scaling-stroke и preserveAspectRatio

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Добавление анимации

Берется соседний цвет градиента по точкам `offset`

```
values="violet;blue;violet"
```

Анимируется атрибут линейного градиента `stop-color`

`<linearGradient id="linearGradient" x1="-36" x2="200" y1="148" y2="148" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop style="stop-color:violet" offset="0">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="0.5s" values="violet;blue;violet" begin="rec.click" repeatCount="2" />
   </stop>`

и так для каждой точки `offset`

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 237 113" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient" x1="-36" x2="200" y1="148" y2="148" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop style="stop-color:violet" offset="0">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="0.5s" values="violet;blue;violet" begin="rec.click" repeatCount="2" />
   </stop>
   <stop style="stop-color:blue" offset="0.5">
    <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.0s" values="blue;orange;blue" begin="rec.click" repeatCount="2" />
   </stop>
   <stop style="stop-color:orange" offset="1">
    <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.5s" values="orange;violet;orange" begin="rec.click" repeatCount="2" />
   </stop>
  
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g id="rec" transform="translate(36 -91)">
  <rect  x="-35" y="93" width="230" height="106" ry="18" style="fill:transparent;stroke-width:3;stroke:url(#linearGradient)"/>
   <text x="0" y="158" font-size="48" fill="gray" >Click me</text>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

*Добавим анимацию для текста кнопки.*

Для этого просто используем уже созданный градиент с анимацией к тексту

```
<text x="0" y="158" font-size="48" fill="url(#linearGradient)" >Click me</text>
```

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 237 113" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient" x1="-36" x2="200" y1="148" y2="148" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop style="stop-color:violet" offset="0">
   <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="0.8s" values="violet;blue;violet" begin="rec.click" repeatCount="2" />
   </stop>
   <stop style="stop-color:blue" offset="0.8">
    <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.0s" values="blue;orange;blue" begin="rec.click" repeatCount="2" />
   </stop>
   <stop style="stop-color:orange" offset="1">
    <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.5s" values="orange;violet;orange" begin="rec.click" repeatCount="2" />
   </stop>
  
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g id="rec" transform="translate(36 -91)">
  <rect  x="-35" y="93" width="234" height="110" ry="18" style="fill:transparent;stroke-width:2;stroke:url(#linearGradient)"/>
   <text x="0" y="158" font-size="48" fill="url(#linearGradient)" >Click me</text>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ubuntu User твой ответ с вариантами анимации

Comment: спасибо.....познавательно

Answer (score 4):

В вашем примере я не увидел реализацию на svg а хотелось бы увидеть что не получилось

Так же в вашем примере есть clip-path который поддерживается но не везде, от пример реализации прямоугольника с закруглёнными углами и с градиентной заливкой stroke

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 237 113" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient" x1="-36" x2="200" y1="148" y2="148" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop style="stop-color:violet" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:blue" offset="0.5"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:orange" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(36 -91)">
  <rect x="-35" y="93" width="234" height="110" ry="18" style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke:url(#linearGradient)"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к посту! Проблема с SVG была в отсутствии возможности обернуть все это дело в CSS class в виде background, svg gradient из иллюстратора "поплыл" при масштабировании блоков. Возможно ли приведенный Вами код упаковать в класс для последующего вызова повсеместно в шаблоне без проблем с масштабированием?

Comment: background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,....);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

Но высота зависит от ширины и нижнюю часть не видно...

Comment: @UbuntuUser Хороший ответ (+)

Comment: MaximLensky, добрый день. Ссылка, которую Вы дали в комментарии на Codepen к сожалению не работает. Расскажите пожалуйста - как можно сделать Ваше решение с произвольной высотой/шириной, подстраиваюшейся под контейнер ?

Comment: @ГайратВласов я удалил этот пример на codepen, скажи что там было ? просто я не помню что я там делал

Comment: Ок, тогда я вопрос сформулирую.
Вы написали
viewBox="0 0 237 113"
и задали фиксированное соотношение сторон.

Вопрос: можно ли написать <div><svg></div> и для div задать некоторый произвольный размер, и чтобы при этом svg вписалось в размер div ?

Т.е. у div соотношение сторон не будет соответсвовать 237/113 ?

Comment: У Вас почему то письмо на gmail не прошло. На какой адрес можно написать ?
ggvlasov@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

В целом вопрос такой - есть прямоугольная рамка на SVG.
Рамка находится внутри div произвольного неизвестного размера.
Можно ли ее сделать так, чтобы она вписалась в div ?

```
<div><svg></div>
```

```css
div {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  /*   Когда размер совпадает с заданным - то все хорошо 
  width:calc(10px + 240px * 2.5);
  height:calc(10px + 120px * 2.5);  */
  /*    как можно заставить svg растянуться по высоте когда размер контейнера не соответсвует viebox ?*/
  width: calc(10px + 200px * 2.5);
  height: calc(10px + 120px * 2.5);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 240 120">
     <defs>
      <linearGradient id="linearGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(40)"  >
       <stop style="stop-color:violet; stop-opacity: .7;" offset="0%"/>
       <stop style="stop-color:blue; stop-opacity: .4;" offset="40%"/>
       <stop style="stop-color:orange" offset="90%"/>
      </linearGradient>
     </defs>

     <g >
       <rect x="5" y="5" width="230" height="110" ry="10" 
             style="fill:none;stroke-width:5;stroke:url(#linearGradient);"/> 
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

В приведенном примере если div задать такой размер - то рамка туда прекрасно впишется (с учетом padding):
  width:calc(10px + 240px * 2.5);
  height:calc(10px + 120px * 2.5);

Если поломать соотношение сторон - то в примере видно что рамка до нижней границы не дотягивается.